# Any way to remove "cut", "copy", "create shortcut", "delete" and "rename" from context menus?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

The only information I've found online that goes to any actual length to attempt to address this matter is an old thread I found on sevenforums that recommended using resource hacker to remove specific lines from the language pack Windows is using in order to nuke these superfluous context menu items but that solution doesn't appear to function in Win10. Here's the link:

http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/170036-remove-create-shortcut-file-folder-context-menu-2.html

All other "answers" to other people posing this or a similar question have either been suggestions it isn't possible or condescending folk questioning why anyone would want to remove these items to begin with.

Comment: [be nice](http://superuser.com/help/behavior) - some of the language in the original question was inappropriate for the site. It would also be *super cool* If you mention what you're trying to do - is this a kiosk style setup? Do you need this for one or all users?

Comment: This is for personal use. It's of no relevance to me if a solution applies to all users or not.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the post you are looking for. [Context menu editors](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors)

Listed on the page are several options to Add, Remove, Edit Context Menu items in Windows 7 / 8 / 10

Viewing the page you have two options that you can use in order to edit choices in the context menu.

**Registry Method**

Using Registry Editor and run the following key

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

Of course you should also be careful when editing anything in the registry so be sure to create a back up just to be safe.

**Context Menu Editors**

To name a few.
Ultimate Windows Customizer
Right-Click Extender for Windows
Context Menu Editor for Windows 
ContextEdit

All of which have the same context in order to use a 3rd party program to change the context menu content.

Comment: **NONE** of the items described above appear in the registry.

**NONE** of the third party tools you list are able to edit these items.